# unresolved reference in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I created a new model and anylogic gives me this error and it doesn't download 3d object during simulation.What's wrong?thanks
[image: error]

[image: image error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies list is a list of all other packages (read models or libraries) that this model requires to run.

If you referenced or dragged an object from one model to another it will create a dependency. See below

[image]

I dragged truck from model 39 and placed it on main in model 40.

If you are sure you don't need anymore you can safely remove it.